# What are approved French travel agents whose organised trip grants Visa-free entry to French overseas territories

Tags: visa-free-entry, tours, chinese-citizens, new-caledonia

[As per wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policies_of_the_French_overseas_departments_and_territories), citizens from a group of developing countries (China, India etc) enjoy Visa-free entry of up to 15 days for each stay in New Caledonia and French Polynesia, for trips organized by an approved travel agency.

The problem is such travel agencies are nowhere to be found. Wikipedia sourced information from the pages of French government websites. For example, regarding rules of la Nouvelle-Calédonie (New Caledonia), this web page:

https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000024389411

Quote the text from Chine (China) part:

> - pour les séjours d'une durée inférieure à quinze jours pour les ressortissants dont le voyage et le séjour sont organisés par l'intermédiaire d'une agence agréée.

The word "approved", here *agréée*, is not to be found again in the same page. It's left undefined.

To put this discussion to context, I'm searching for an organised tour to New Caledonia for my Chinese parents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that there is a list although it is quite hard to track down.

https://cn.ambafrance.org/Agences-de-voyages-chinoises-agreees-pour-organiser-des

It seems to be a list of agencies in China but from your question I suspect that is what you need. It is in French but since you have linked to a French language site I assume that is not a problem for you.